# Why is list.remove(value) not working at all?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
def game():
    for i in range(0, 10):
        questions = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        randomInt = choice(questions)
        print(formatIt(songs[randomInt], artists[randomInt]))
        questions.remove(randomInt)
```

(`formatIt` is one of my own functions and `choice` is `random.choice`)

Everything works as it should until the `questions.remove` at the bottom, which does nothing (with no error message). I have tried changing the list items to strings; using a set rather than a list, but this isn't compatible with the `random.choice`and changing the variable to an actual value, but the list stays unchanged.

Comment: You need to remove an object, not index

Comment: Use ```questions.remove(questions[randomInt])```

Answer (score 1):

Two things, firstly:

```
questions.remove(questions[randint(0,9)])   # otherwise it can try removing like 65 or something
```

Secondly: I don't know if it's intended, but in every step inside loop you are bringing questions back to its original state. If you dont want that, put this line before for:

```
def game():
    questions = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    for i in range(0, 10):
        # rest of code
```

Comment: No problem mate, everyone is constantly making mistakes in simplest tasks. That's the part of this job :)